# How to make a save action that checks whether a 'save-as' has already been performed

Tags: user-interface, netbeans, save, menuitem, save-as

I have researched and tried to refer back to my fileChooser.getSeletedFile() in my save as action but can not work out how to check whether or not a file has been created. Here is my attempted code so far:

**Save as code(works well):**

```
public void Save_As() {

    fileChooserTest.setApproveButtonText("Save");
    int actionDialog = fileChooserTest.showOpenDialog(this);

    File fileName = new File(fileChooserTest.getSelectedFile() + ".txt");
    try {
        if (fileName == null) {
            return;
        }

        BufferedWriter outFile = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName));
        outFile.write(this.jTextArea2.getText());//put in textfile
        outFile.flush(); // redundant, done by close()
        outFile.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }
}
```

**"Save" code doesn't work:**

```
private void SaveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    File f = fileChooserTest.getSelectedFile();
    try {
        if (f.exists()) {
            BufferedWriter bw1 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileChooserTest.getSelectedFile() + ".txt"));
            bw1 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileChooserTest.getSelectedFile() + ".txt"));

            String text = ((JTextArea) jTabbedPane1.getSelectedComponent()).getText();
            bw1.write(text);
            bw1.close();
        } else {
            Save_As();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing an instance to the `JFileChooser` rather store an instance to the `File` (wich will be `null` before any save has been performed). In your `SaveActionPerformed` method check if the file is `null`. If it is `null` then do a `Save_As` and store the selected file in your file variable, if it is not `null` then do a normal save into the file.